# Echoing current category's slug on custom post type single post on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Everyone

I tried to echo current category slug on custom post type single post, but it seems like i've miss something important. Since the slug is not echoed. i've tried a different way to solve this, but there are no way it works.
to give you the context, the slug should be echoed on the anchor link, so i can make a Back Button on single post to direct user to category view.

It would be great if anyone can help me on this. Thanks a lot.

```
 <?php
                        if('product' == get_post_type()) {
                            $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->slug,'category');
                        ?>
                        
                        <center><a href="../../product-category/<?php echo $terms->slug ?>" class="grve-btn grve-btn-small grve-square grve-bg-primary-1 grve-bg-hover-black">Back</a></center>
```

Comment: Check the response for get_post_type()... are you getting "product" as a response.

Comment: @Anand i have checked, and it works perfectly fine. i am getting products as a response